# integrate an ant project

Tags: eclipse, ant, integration

I want to run a following project:

https://gforge.inria.fr/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/melinda/index.php/RDF_keys

In the project page, they resume the steps as the following:

```
1-git clone https://gforge.inria.fr/git/melinda/melinda.git
2-cd melinda/trunk/rdfifd/
3-ant jar
4- java -jar pseudo-keys.jar -t  -i /path/to/rdf_file -o /path/to/output/file
```

So how can i integrate and run this project in an eclipse project?

I already following these setp on a linux command line and it is work well and pseudo-keys.jar is generated. I take this .jar and In my laptop i write the following code:

```
public class TestDriver {
     /** Executes a command */
      public static void execute(String cmd, File folder) throws Exception {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, folder);
        BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String s1, s2 = null;
        while (null != (s1 = bri.readLine()) || null != (s2 = bre.readLine())) {
          if (s1 != null) System.out.println(s1);
          if (s2 != null) System.err.println(s2);
        }
        p.waitFor();
      }

    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
        String cmd = "java -jar C:/Users/user/Desktop/pseudo-keys.jar -t  -i C:/Users/user/Desktop/randomLocation/datasetLocation/restaurant1.rdf -o C:/Users/user/Desktop/randomLocation/key.xml";
        execute(cmd, null);
    }
```

The execution give the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

Any help please to run the code? Where is my mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the URI `https://gforge.inria.fr/git/melinda/melinda.git` to the clipboard
2. In the ***Git Repositories*** click the ***Clone a Git Repository*** button and follow the wizard (if the dialog is not prefilled, enter the URI manually)
3. Right-click the node ***melinda [master] > Working Tree > trunk > rdfifd*** and choose ***Import Projects...*** and follow the import wizard
4. In the *Package Explorer* or *Project Explorer* **open** the file **`rdfifd/build.xml`** via double-click
5. In the *Outline* view right-click the target **`jar`** and choose ***Run As > Ant Build***
6. On the command line run **`java -jar pseudo-keys.jar -t  -i /path/to/rdf_file -o /path/to/output/file`**. Alternatively, you can skip step 4 and 5 and **run `fr.inrialpes.exmo.rdfkeys.KeyExtraction` as Java application** with the necessary arguments (*Run > Run Configurations...*, in tab *Arguments* field *Program arguments*).

Comment: Sir @howlger, thank you. With your hints the software is running in eclipse. But please how can integrate this project in my own java project. how can ass the argument inthe code not in Run configuration

Comment: @bib You can also call the main method of `fr.inrialpes.exmo.rdfkeys.KeyExtraction` in your Java code, e. g. `KeyExtraction.main(new String[]{"-t", "-i", "/path/to/rdf_file", "-o", "/path/to/output/file"})`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir @howlger